Array/List selection
Description: Running into an issue with trying to get a value into a hash table. Code below should get the file path for a bunch of components (that part works) and puts them into an array and sorts it. Then a hashtable is created that has the filepath as the name and the component ID as the value. The value is gathered off -split on the file path name. This part is testing and working, but when I try the below, I get

Cannot index into a null array.

I've tested with the .Add(filepath[1],RandomValue) and that works but when I try the .Add(filepath[1],-split), it fails with the null array. I intend to put this in a loop but for now just getting a single value to work will be enough to go from.
Code:
$fullPathU3 = (Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\Example\Component\Place\Ready" -Recurse -Depth 1| Where-Object {($_.Name -like "*thing") -and ($_.Name -Notlike "*unlinke*") -and ($_.Name -Notlike "*old*")}).fullName
$fullPathU3 = $fullPathU3 | sort


$fileCompTable = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable 
$fileCompTable = @{}

$fileCompTable.Add($fullPathU3[1] , ($fullPathU3[1] -split "\\")[5])



The error is stating that $fullPathU3 is null. As aside, you're adding a scriptblock as your key value. Those { ... } shouldn't be there.

I've got those removed. If I put say $fileCompTable.Add($fullPathU3[1] ,123) it doesn't complain and it adds to $fileCompTable

Can you post a few sample file paths?

For security reason I'm not able to, but I think I've got it figure out. I've got one array for the file paths, a second array for the component id and then put them into the hashtable. Probably not the right way to go about it, but it functions.

Try doing Write-Host $fullPathU3.Length at the 2nd or 3rd line. If it shows 0 then the Where-Object filters out all items and then you are not allowed to do $fullPathU3[1]. At least that is when I get the "Cannot index into a null array." error.

@aarogrill Let's take a made-up example then - let's say you discover the files P:\Example\Component\Place\Ready\a.txt and P:\Example\Component\Place\Ready\nested\b.txt - what would the component ID be for either of those?

Why are there c# and .net tags?

@Mathias it would be ready and  nested. Essentially I'm trying to generate a listbox with the components in alphabetical order, then use the selected object in the listbox to open the excel file in the background for the component and populate visual fields.

@aarogrill Ahh, I see. In that case you might want to use FileInfo.Directory.Name or $_.FullName |Split-Path -Parent |Split-Path -Leaf. I've updated my answer below

Thank you for the suggestions. I ended up figuring it out using a hashtable and having the component id be the key and the file path the value then calling what I needed. So far my prototype is functioning!

There's no need to explicitly index into the array of collected paths - just iterate over the array with ForEach-Object:
$fileSystemItems = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\Example\Component\Place\Ready" -Recurse -Depth 1 -File |Where-Object {($_.Name -like "*thing") -and ($_.Name -Notlike "*unlinke*") -and ($_.Name -Notlike "*old*")}

$fileCompTable = @{}
$fileSystemItems |ForEach-Object {
  $compID = ($_.FullName -split '\\')[5]
  $fileCompTable[$_.FullName] = $compID
}

If you want the last part of the file path (eg. the file/folder name), simply reference the Name property on the original file system object:
$fileCompTable[$_.FullName] = $_.Name

If you want the name of the immediate parent directory of a file:
$fileCompTable[$_.FullName] = $_.Directory.Name


There were few issues with your script, I have reworked it as follows:
$path = "P:\Example\Component\Place\Ready"

$fileCompTable = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable 
$fileCompTable = @{}

$fullPathU3 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Depth 1 | Where-Object {($_.Name -like "*thing") -and ($_.Name -Notlike "*unlinke*") -and ($_.Name -Notlike "*old*")}
Write-Output "Items:"
$fullPathU3
$fullPathU3 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $fileCompTable.Add($_.FullName , $_.Name)
}

Write-Output "Hashtable:"
$fileCompTable


().fullName was used on collection, if you want to apply it to
each element you can use piping, similar to C# LINQ Select
[5] is not the best way to get last element of array, I suggest using
[-1] indexer
I reworked your code do a foreach and add all
elements
{($fullPathU3[1] -split "\\")[-1]} was in fact treated as a code block type object, instead of evaluating the value
I edited answer to simply use .Name property instead of splitting file name and looking for last element ;)


If he want the last index -1, mind as well use .Name no? :)

correct, he could use .Name instead of splitting and taking last element, which would be even better, agreed :)

Here, a commented example base on everybody else' work
# No reason for the full object declaration, this is enough to make a empty
# hashtable while also being very easy to read and understand.  
$fileCompTable = @{}

# Evaluate adding the -File parameter if you are interested only in files and not directories.   
# Or the parameter -Directory in the opposite case.   
# moved '*thing' in the filter of Get-ChildItem to maximise efficiency following the Filter Left doctrine.   
$fullPathU3 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Depth 1 -Filter '*thing' | 
    # Parenthesis are useless in this instance.   
    # Evaluate using Where-Object -Property Name -notmatch '(unlinke|old)' instead.   
    Where-Object { $_.Name -Notlike '*unlinke*' -and $_.Name -Notlike '*old*' }

Write-Host 'Items:' -ForegroundColor Yellow
$fullPathU3

# If you have a collection already in memory in a variable, Foreach() is the most efficient loop.   
# Not like one can notice any real difference under the 1000 items.   
foreach ($File in $fullPathU3) { $fileCompTable.Add($File.FullName , $File.Name) }

Write-Host 'Hashtable:' -ForegroundColor Yellow
$fileCompTable

